# Error in pipeline while seeking using GST_FORMAT_TIME

Tags: udp, streaming, gstreamer, rtp, seek

I have below pipeline,

```
gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location=video.ts ! \
    tsdemux name=demux program-number=10 demux.video_012c ! \
    queue ! muxer.sink_300 mpegtsmux name=muxer prog-map=program_map,sink_300=10 ! \
    rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=192.168.2.194 port=8765 sync=true async=false qos=true
```

And i would like to seek this pipeline to some duration, for that i used the code as below

```
if(!gst_element_seek_simple(pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, (pos*1000000000)))
{
    UU_PRINT("Player Seek Failed in Stream File Play !!\n");
}
```

By using above code, seeking is getting succeeded.

But i am receiving below critical messages,

```
 (uuMediaPlayer:8051): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed
 BUS_MESSAGE :: Warning : Internal data flow problem., gstbasesink.c(3307): gst_base_sink_chain_unlocked (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0:
Received buffer without a new-segment. Assuming timestamps start from 0.
Seek Called

(uuMediaPlayer:8051): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed

(uuMediaPlayer:8051): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed
 BUS_MESSAGE :: Warning : Internal data flow problem., gstbasesink.c(3307): gst_base_sink_chain_unlocked (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0:
Received buffer without a new-segment. Assuming timestamps start from 0.

(uuMediaPlayer:8051): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed

(uuMediaPlayer:8051): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed

(uuMediaPlayer:8051): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed

(uuMediaPlayer:8051): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion 'segment->format == format' failed
```

Why these messages are coming, how to resolve this issue?